# One to many relationship with gorm in golang doesnt work

Tags: mysql, rest, go, go-gorm

I have two tables:

```
type Person struct {
    ID int
    FirstName string
    LastName string
    Functions []Function
}

type Function struct {
    gorm.Model
    Info string
    Person Person
}
```

I create the tables like this:

```
db.AutoMigrate(&models.Person{}, &models.Function{})
```

I then initialize the database:

```
user := models.Person{
    FirstName: "Isa",
    LastName:  "istcool",
    Functions: []models.Function{{Info: "Trainer"}, {Info: "CEO"}},
}
db.Create(&user)
```

Now the problem is that my `Person` table only got `Firstname` and `Lastname` columns and my `Function` table only got the `Info` column.
But when I start my `GET` request I get people with the column function which is always null.

[Here is a screenshot from my GET request and my db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bdKdo.jpg)

To see the code visit my [GitHub repo](https://github.com/Gnadlinger/SpommunicateBackend.git)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally found the answer!!
The problem is my GET functions I have to use

```
db.Preload("Functions").Find(&[]models.Person{})
```

instead of

```
db.Find(&[]models.Person{})
```